# Why do Scrum user stories only use the Fibonacci series?

Tags: scrum, user-stories, story-points

I know that user stories in Scrum are measured with a Modified Fibonacci sequence (`0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 20, 40...`). Why does Scrum *only* use [Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) to estimate stories?

Comment: Already answered on another site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362286/why-is-the-fibonacci-series-used-in-agile-planning-poker

Comment: Folks, I don't think this question is an exact duplicate. While the questions are closely related, I think the OP for *this* question is asking why one can't use other measures for estimating story points, while [Why would teams use the Fibonnacci sequence for story points?](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/4251/fibonnacci-sequence-as-story-points) asks about the pros and cons of Fibonacci numbers as a metric. I've tried to clarify the question, and am voting to re-open.

Comment: +1 for the OP for raising what I believe to be a common mis-perception.

Answer (score 32):

### No Fibonacci Required

While many agile practitioners have embraced a modified or unmodified Fibonacci sequence for story-point estimation, neither story points nor user stories are actually requirements of the Scrum methodology.

Even if you embrace the *practice* of estimating with story-points and user stories, you can use any relative-sizing tools you want. Some examples I've seen in the field include:

- T-shirt sizes (e.g. S, M, L, XL)
- Traffic lights (green, yellow, red)
- [Starbucks drink sizes](http://coffeetea.about.com/od/coffeebasics/f/Starbucks-Sizes.htm) (*demi*, short, tall, *grande*, *venti*, *trenta*)
- Simple sequences such as 1-5 or 1-10.

If you decide to use story points, the key is to unmoor the points from time estimates. This helps to avoid [anchoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchoring), and hopefully prevents estimates from being used improperly as a productivity-management metric rather than a planning or forecasting tool.

Feel free to use whatever scale works for your team. However, I'd certainly recommend sticking with Mike Cohn's [Planning Poker Fibonacci sequence](http://store.mountaingoatsoftware.com/pages/faqs) unless you have a strong reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Excellent answer @CodeGnome!

Comment: Yes, We use Poker system and it works good. since all the members of team add inputs according to their work complexity & size,  and reach to final conclusion what should be the final story size.

Comment: I always wanted to use totally abstract measures, like "S,M,L". But I do that how would I measure the average velocity? How would I know when the project would possibly be finished? If I use numbers I can easily calculate - the average velocity is, lets say, 15 - in that case if there are 60 points in the project backlog left, I would know, that the project should be finished in moreless 4 iterations. Can you do the same using abstact relative sizings?

Answer (score 20):

One main reason is to not have debates/estimates like: 19,20, 21, 23 Story Points.

In agile estimation is usually about comparing **relative size**, it's clear that 1 Story Point is significantly smaller than 10 Story Points, but 10 SP vs 9 SP is not much different.

You want to make sure that bigger numbers are **rough** estimates and you're not sending to your stakeholders message that you know exactly how big item is.

BTW: That's the reason you have **20** instead of **21** which is valid Fibonnaci sequence number.

The Fibonacci series also better represents the fact that uncertainty grows proportionally with the size of the story. The differences between 1, 2 and 3 point stories are probably better understood than the differences between a 20 and a 40. This is reflected in the distance between story sizes.

Comment: The Fibonacci series also better represents the fact that uncertainty grows proportionally with the size of the story. The differences between 1,2 and 3 point stories are probably better understood the the differences between a 20 and a 40. This is reflected in the distance between story sizes.

Comment: @Willl Yes, of course, feel free to edit my answer and thanks fro input.